# How to extract a 2D plane from a 3D numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, grid, plane

**[TLDR]:**

Essentially my question boils down to how one can extract the 2d data of a  plane from a 3D numpy meshgrid

**[Detailed Description]:**

I am calculating the electric field of two (or more) point charges. I did this in 2D and can plot the results via matplotlib using quiver or streamplot

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

eps_0 = 8e-12
fac = (1./(4*np.pi*eps_0))

charges  = [1.0,-1.0]
qx       = [-2.0,2.0]
qy       = [0.0,0.0]

# GRID
gridsize = 4.0
N = 11
X,Y = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-gridsize,gridsize,N),
                   np.linspace(-gridsize,gridsize,N))
# CALC E-FIELD   
sumEx = np.zeros_like(X)
sumEy = np.zeros_like(Y)

for q, qxi, qyi in zip(charges,qx,qy):
    dist_vec_x = X - qxi
    dist_vec_y = Y - qyi 
    dist = np.sqrt(dist_vec_x**2 + dist_vec_y**2)

    Ex = fac * q * (dist_vec_x/dist**3)
    Ey = fac * q * (dist_vec_y/dist**3)

    sumEx += Ex
    sumEy += Ey

# PLOT
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.streamplot(X,Y,sumEx,sumEy)
plt.show()
```

This produces the correct results
[image: 2D dipole]

I can easily extend this to 3D

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

eps_0 = 8e-12
fac = (1./(4*np.pi*eps_0))

charges = [1.0,-1.0]
qx      = [-2.0,2.0]
qy      = [0.0,0.0]
qz      = [0.0,0.0]

# GRID
gridsize = 4.0
N = 11
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-gridsize,gridsize,N),
                     np.linspace(-gridsize,gridsize,N),
                     np.linspace(-gridsize,gridsize,N))

# CALC E-FIELD   
sumEx = np.zeros_like(X)
sumEy = np.zeros_like(Y)
sumEz = np.zeros_like(Z)
for q, qxi, qyi, qzi in zip(charges,qx,qy,qz):
    dist_vec_x = X - qxi
    dist_vec_y = Y - qyi
    dist_vec_z = Z - qzi

    dist = np.sqrt(dist_vec_x**2 + dist_vec_y**2 + dist_vec_z**2)

    Ex = fac * q * (dist_vec_x/dist**3)
    Ey = fac * q * (dist_vec_y/dist**3)
    Ez = fac * q * (dist_vec_z/dist**3)

    sumEx += Ex
    sumEy += Ey
    sumEz += Ez  

# PLOT
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(X,Y,Z,sumEx,sumEy,sumEz, pivot='middle', normalize=True)
plt.show()
```

This also yields the correct result when plotted in 3D (as far as I can tell)

[image: 3D dipole]

But for some reason I can not figure out how to extract the data from one x-y plane from the generated 3D numpy mesh. I thought I could just do something like

```
zplane = round(N/2)
ax.quiver(X,Y,sumEx[:,:,zplane],sumEy[:,:,zplane])
```

but this does not do the trick. Does anyone know the proper way here?

Comment: What does "does not do the trick" mean? Is the plot incorrect? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `projection='3d'` and index `X` and `Y`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
zplane = round(N / 2)
ax.quiver(X[:, :, zplane], Y[:, :, zplane], sumEx[:, :, zplane], sumEy[:, :, zplane])
plt.show()
```

If you select a specific `zplane` your plot is no longer a 3D-plot.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not it. It’s not like I cannot plot anything.  It’s just not the plane that I am expecting to get.

Comment: Oh right, you need to index `X` and `Y` as well. Updated my answer.

Comment: Oh my god, you are correct. I don't know why, but I took me hours and I couldn't figure it out. X-D Thank you for the hint!

Comment: You are welcome and may also upvote my answer if it helped you. :) If you want to modify your plot in some special ways, take a look at the `LineCollection` module of `matplotlib`, as `quiver` returns a `LineCollection`.

Comment: Follow up question: How would you slice a plane in any other direction, e.g. in the X-Z direction? Wouldn't this be something like: 
 `ax.quiver(X[:,yplane,:],Z[:,yplane,:],sumEx[:,yplane,:],sumEz[:,yplane,:])`

Comment: Your meshgrid is made for 3D... So using your meshgrid the `yplane` would be: `ax.quiver(X[:,:,yplane],Y[:,yplane],sumEx[:,yplane,:],sumEy[:,yplane,:])`

Comment: You can also just make a 2d meshgrid with `numpy` which is returning you 2D `X` and `Y`: `X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-4, 4.1, .8), np.arange(-4, 4.1, .8))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171630/discussion-between-wiggles-and-scotty1).

Comment: But why? I answered your question on the `zplane`. Which is what your question was about. So the answer should be marked as accepted. I even gave an answer to your follow up question in chat. This answer also works, but you need to select the plane using an if-else-clause before. But nevertheless the accepted answer should be based on your question here. For follow up questions you should just open another question. This is even in the stackoverflow rules...